# Accessing to components of derived types which extends main derived type by using inheritance rule

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I need a little help about using inheritance rules. My intention is to use one derived type array for storaging results of calculation but i want to use that array also for storaging components values from main and extended derived types. 
For example, this is my example code which I want to transform:

```
MODULE DERIVED_TYPES

IMPLICIT NONE

! FIRST DERIVED TYPE

TYPE, PUBLIC :: DT_AA

  INTEGER, PRIVATE :: I_AA

  CONTAINS

  PROCEDURE, PUBLIC:: CALCULATE => CALC_DATA_I_AA
  PROCEDURE, PUBLIC::    T_I_AA => TAKE_DATA_I_AA

END TYPE DT_AA

PRIVATE :: CALC_DATA_I_AA
PRIVATE :: TAKE_DATA_I_AA

! SECOND DERIVED TYPE

TYPE, EXTENDS( DT_AA ), PUBLIC :: DT_BB

  INTEGER, PRIVATE :: I_BB

  CONTAINS

  PROCEDURE, PUBLIC:: CALCULATE => CALC_DATA_I_BB
  PROCEDURE, PUBLIC::    T_I_BB => TAKE_DATA_I_BB

END TYPE DT_BB

PRIVATE :: CALC_DATA_I_BB
PRIVATE :: TAKE_DATA_I_BB

CONTAINS

! TYPE DT_AA PROCEDURES

  SUBROUTINE CALC_DATA_I_AA( THIS, INDX )

    CLASS( DT_AA ) :: THIS
    INTEGER, INTENT( IN ) :: INDX

    THIS%I_AA = 1 + INDX

  END SUBROUTINE CALC_DATA_I_AA

  FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_I_AA( THIS ) RESULT( VALUE_I_AA )

    CLASS( DT_AA ) THIS
    INTEGER :: VALUE_I_AA

    VALUE_I_AA = THIS%I_AA

  END FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_I_AA

! TYPE DT_BB PROCEDURES

  SUBROUTINE CALC_DATA_I_BB( THIS, INDX )

    CLASS( DT_BB ) :: THIS
    INTEGER, INTENT( IN ) :: INDX

    THIS%I_BB = THIS%I_AA + INDX

  END SUBROUTINE CALC_DATA_I_BB

  FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_I_BB( THIS ) RESULT( VALUE_I_BB )

    CLASS( DT_BB ) THIS
    INTEGER :: VALUE_I_BB

    VALUE_I_BB = THIS%I_BB

  END FUNCTION TAKE_DATA_I_BB

END MODULE DERIVED_TYPES

PROGRAM INHERITANCE_RULE

USE, NON_INTRINSIC :: DERIVED_TYPES

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER :: I
INTEGER, PARAMETER :: N_CALC = 3

CLASS( DT_AA ), POINTER :: P_INH
 TYPE( DT_AA ),  TARGET :: P_A_INH( N_CALC )

DO I = 1, N_CALC

   P_INH => P_A_INH( I )

   CALL P_INH%CALCULATE( I )

   WRITE(*,*) P_INH%T_I_AA(), P_INH%T_I_BB()

END DO

END PROGRAM INHERITANCE_RULE
```

In this case I can not use pointer `P_INH` and function for taking component `I_BB` values which is not member of extended derived type because I got this compile error message:

`'t_i_bb'  is not a member of the 'dt_aa' structure`

Which kind of change is useful for this case?

My IDE is Code::Blocks 17.12 with Gfortran compiler. The version of compiler is: MinGW 6.3.0.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I want to make calculation on both structures at same time and I want to take values by functions. Is there way for doing that?

Comment: Useful for what? To fix the error message? Or to achieve something else?

Comment: @VladimirF I can fix error by different array declaring but in that case I will not get correct result for a `I_AA`.

Comment: What do you expect/want the values of `I_AA` and `I_BB` to be after your loop?

Comment: @ptb I want to get this result `[2,3], [3,4], [5,6]` and I want to storage these results in array `P_A_INH`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, the desired outcome is to call the `calculate` routines associated with the base and derived type and access the `take` routines associated with the base and derived type.  This has to be done through the derived type as the base knows nothing about the types which extend it.  One way to achieve this without modifying your types is:

```
type(dt_bb) :: b(n_calc)

do i = 1, n_calc

    call b(i)%dt_aa%calculate(i)
    call b(i)%calculate(i)

    write(*,*) b(i)%t_i_aa(), b(i)%t_i_bb()

end do
```

The output of the above is:

```
       2           3
       3           5
       4           7
```

The order of the `calculate` calls should be chosen to match your use case.

Edit:
To expand on my comment,  If you modify the definition of `calc_data_i_bb` to:

```
subroutine calc_data_i_bb( this, indx )

    class( dt_bb ) :: this
    integer, intent( in ) :: indx

    call this%dt_aa%calculate(indx)
    this%i_bb = this%i_aa + indx

end subroutine calc_data_i_bb
```

Then you can simplify the driver loop:

```
type(dt_bb) :: b(n_calc)

do i = 1, n_calc

    call b(i)%calculate(i)

    write(*,*) b(i)%t_i_aa(), b(i)%t_i_bb()

end do
```

This may be a better option depending on the use case.

Comment: This solution is correct from final result point of view but...I want to know is it possible to get correct result with one call of function `calculation` for bouth structures or it is not possible at all.

Comment: The two function calls must be made explicitly.  You can move the call    `this%dt_aa%calculate` to `calc_data_i_bb` to try to hide it but it is still two function calls

Comment: That is good because I want to hide to module that call from host program.